# Is that posible to select spefic wiki page from wiki library through a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, workflow-lookup

I am trying to select a specific wiki page from wiki library through a workflow. Then by the condition on its approval status want to update another specific item in another list.

For Example, There is are 8 wiki pages in wiki library. Each has their completion status in another list called 'completion status' list. So there are total 8 statuses in that list. when an approver approves a wiki page then based on its approval status I want the respective status should change in 'completion status' list.

I am unable to do it SharePoint only allows the overall library or a current item in look-up. I am unable to select a specific item from look-up.